# Cannot navigate down

Tags: emacs, emacsw32, dired

After upgrading to *GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2013-03-17 on MARVIN* and *Dired+ 20130812.1425 (elpa)*, navigation in Dired+ is broken.

See screenshot below. When pressing the arrow-down key (`diredp-next-line`) I cannot move beyond `a_file_with_very_long_name`.

What could be a fix?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug -- should be fixed now. Thanks for the report. Please download the latest [`dired+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/dired%2b.el). Let me know if you still see the problem.  Thx -- Drew